# Difference between heat capacities $C_p - C_v$

Tags: thermodynamics

I am trying to prove the following relation between heat capacities:
$$
C_p - C_v = T\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_{P}
$$

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relations_between_heat_capacities#Derivation), they use the fact that
$$
dV = \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_{P}dT + \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)_{T}dP
$$

But do not explain how to derive this fact. How can we know that $V$ is not also a function of entropy? Maybe a function of energy?

Answer (score 1):

For a single phase system of constant composition at thermodynamic equilibrium, the thermodynamic state of the system is completely determined by specifying any **two** intensive properties. This follows from the phase rule, which is an empirical relationship developed by Gibbs.  In this case, the two intensive properties are T and P.

This is not how I would have derived the desired relationship.  I would have started with  $$dH=C_pdT+\left[V-T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P\right]dP$$

Comment: So the choice of $T,P$ is arbitrary? If magnetic field was around, magnetization and for example pressure would have determined the same system as $T,P$?

Comment: I'm not sure about case of a magnetic field.  In this problem, the choice of T,P is not arbitrary.  It is the form that is needed to derive the desired relationship.